# how to convert string to dateformat dd/MM/yyyy

Tags: android

```
String date = '15/2/2014'
SimpleDateFormat simpleDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date d = simpleDate.parse(date);
```

now Date d return : `d= Sat Feb 15 00:00:00 MMT 2014`.

I want to get this format `d= '15/2/2014'`

How can I do it?

Comment: In which format you want date? You have specified the formate in which you are getting the date. Specify your question more.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Edit `M` instead of `MM`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
String date="15/02/2014";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

try {
  Date d=dateFormat.parse(date);
  System.out.println("DATE"+d);
  System.out.println("Formated"+dateFormat.format(d));
}
catch(Exception e) {
  //java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: Geting error
  System.out.println("Excep"+e);
}
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this:
(Here you can change `time variable` with your **input string**)

```
String time = "Sun Jul 15 2012 12:22:00 GMT+03:00 (FLE Daylight Time)";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");
Date date = sdf.parse(time);

SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy");
String s=sdf.format(date.getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String dateInString = "07/06/2013";

try 
{

    Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
    System.out.println(date);
    System.out.println(formatter.format(date));

} catch (ParseException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you use just format before the ("dd/mm/yyyy")?

```
String date = '15/2/2014'
SimpleDateFormat simpleDate = new Format("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date d = simpleDate.parse(date);
```

Comment: What is the difference in your answer and OP's question ?

Comment: im not sure really but im assueming that they want the date to always be that format and for it to come after the d=

Comment: Its not that OP wants.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: @LaszloPapp It is an answer: He's suggesting to use `Format` instead of `SimpleDateFormat`. It may not be a *good* answer, but it does attempt to answer the question.

Comment: @Bohemian: but that is not what the OP wants as indicated by GrlsHu. Hence, if anything this should have been a comment IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below

```
String date1 = "31/12/2011";
SimpleDateFormat form = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
java.util.Date d1 = null;
Calendar tdy1;

try {
    d1 = form.parse(date1);
} catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

tdy1 = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println("tdy mnthhhhhhhhhhh " + tdy1.get(Calendar.MONTH));
tdy1.setTime(d1);

System.out.println("Month of date1= " + tdy1.get(Calendar.MONTH));
```

**Note**

> Calendar.MONTH is return integer value and it is start from 0 to 11 means 0=JANUARY and 11=DECEMBER

for more detail check http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#JANUARY