# Android SimpleDateFormat parse error

Tags: java, android

I would like to parse this string: Thu Jan 01 00:00:58 CET 1970

I use this pattern: EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy

But I got this exception: 
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Jan 01 00:00:58 CET 1970" (at offset 20)

stacktrace:

java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Jan 01 00:01:18 CET 1970" (at offset 20)
W/System.err:     at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:571)

system env: android studio 2.0, compileSdkVersion 23, buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
device: HTC One M7, android 5.0.2

Comment: have you tried this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/21793454/1318946

Answer (score 2):

You should create a **test case** and demonstrate the behavior. I did it for you:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import org.junit.Test;

public class DateParseTest {

@Test
public void testDateFormat() {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.US);
    try {
        Date date = dateFormat.parse("Thu Jan 01 00:00:58 CET 1970");
        System.out.println("parsed date:" + date);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }    
}
```

Use an explicit locale setting **Locale.US**. In your case hungarian is the default locale and you have to parse a date string in hungarian format.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy", new Locale("HU"));
String dateString = "P máj. 01 01:00:58 CET 1970";
Date date = dateFormatHu.parse(dateString);
```

Comment: I got parseexception like in my question

Comment: Post your stacktrace and your system environment.

Comment: in android emulator this is working, but on my device not

Comment: What is your default locale? Add a statement to your unit test: Locale.getDefault() and see what it tells you.

Comment: my default locale is hu_HU

Comment: I don't have hungarian locale on my system.
You can try to put an explicit locale into the SimpleDateFormat:
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.US);

Comment: If I set the locale to hungarian, I get the ParseException as well: Locale.forLanguageTag("HU")

Comment: So, I set Locale.getDefault() to the simpledateformat. If the device language is hungarian I get parseexception, but if I set the device language to english everything is working....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111082/discussion-between-jan-and-user3275938).

Comment: Did you recognize my code example? You get the ParseException when parsing an english date string with hungarian locale.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this post [Java Date(0) is not 1/1/1970](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895171/java-date0-is-not-1-1-1970).

All of the issues with the 1/1/1970 date are explained in full detail.